# How to draw bullets from player in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, html5-canvas

I am trying to make an upward scrolling style arcade shooter game. I have gotten stuck on how to draw bullets upward from the player to where the enemies will be. I am using setInterval to repeat the firing action at the location of the player, but the bullets only follow the fighter jet around resetting the interval every time the player moves by its specified amount.

Any help?

Here is my code at the moment.

Thank you in advance.

```js
var project, ctx, img, img2, width, height, mid, midh, startPx, startPy, audio,interval,bulletStartPx,bulletStartPy;
var score = 0;

function setUp() {
 project = document.getElementById("project");
 ctx = project.getContext("2d");
 width = 505;
 height = 900;
 mid = width/2;
 midh = height/2;
 startPx = width/2-30;
 startPy = height-150;

 audio = new Audio("bgm.mp3");
 audio.play();

 img = new Image();
 img2 = new Image();
 img.src = "bg.png";
 img2.src = "fighterjet.png"
 img.onload = function(){
   ctx.shadowColor = "#ffffff";
   ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   ctx.drawImage(img2, startPx, startPy)
 }
 
 window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress);
}

function drawObject(x, y) {
  ctx.drawImage(img2, startPx, startPy)
}

function checkKeyPress(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == "87") {//W(UP)
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    if (startPy >= 20) {
    startPy -= 20;
    }
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img2, startPx, startPy)
  } else if (event.keyCode == "83") {//S(DOWN)
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    if (startPy <= 785) {
    startPy += 20;
    }
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img2, startPx, startPy)
  } else if (event.keyCode == "65") {//A(LEFT)
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    if (startPx >= 0) {
    startPx -= 20;
    }
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img2, startPx, startPy)
  } else if (event.keyCode == "68") {//D(RIGHT)
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    if (startPx <= 410) {
    startPx += 20;
    }
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img2, startPx, startPy)
  } else if (event.keyCode == "72") {
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      bullets();
  }
}
}

function bullets() {
  return setInterval(function(){
          bulletStartPx = startPx+48;
          bulletStartPy = startPy-30;
          ctx.fillStyle = "gold"
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(bulletStartPx,bulletStartPy,5,0,2*Math.PI);
          ctx.fill();
          score += 25; }, 100);
}

function GameOver(){
  document.getElementById('bm').pause();
  ctx.font = '30px Courier New'
  ctx.filltext('GAME OVER', mid, midh)
  ctx.filltext('Your score was: '+score, mid, midh+40)
}

function showScore(){
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000'
  ctx.font = '18px Courier New'
  ctx.text(score, width-10, 15)
}






/*
function bullet(){
  this.x = startPx;
 this.y = startPy - 10;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#b20808";
    ctx.shadowColor = "#b20808";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
    this.y -= bulletSpeed;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 2, 8);
  }
}

function fireGun(){
if (event.keyCode == "32") {
   bullet();
   }
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Project</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="project.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Arcade Shooter</h1>
    <fieldset>
    <legend><h2>Instructions:</h2></legend>
    <h3>Press W, A, S, D to Move</h3>
    <h3>Press Space Bar to Fire</h3>
    <h3>Goal: Survive as long as you can!</h3>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <canvas id="project" style="border-style: solid" width=505 height=900 ></canvas>
    <br>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input id="start" type="button" value="START THE GAME" onclick="setUp()" style="width: 300px">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, if `bullet()` is an object constructor, it should be spelled `Bullet() { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to redefine global variable where you'll keep track of everything :

```
var gameData = {
    interval: null, // Controls the refresh
    redrawRequired: false, // Flag
    allBullets: [], // Moving bullets
    defaultBulletSpeed: 20 // Bullet speed
}
```

2) Only check for action in checkKeyPress(event) function, including the fireGun action :

```
function checkKeyPress(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == "87") {//87 W(UP)
        if (startPy >= 20) {
            startPy -= 20;
            gameData.redrawRequired = true;
        }
    } else if (event.keyCode == "83") {//83 S(DOWN)
        if (startPy <= 785) {
            startPy += 20;
            gameData.redrawRequired = true;
        }
    } else if (event.keyCode == "65") {//65 A(LEFT)
        if (startPx >= 0) {
            startPx -= 20;
            gameData.redrawRequired = true;
        }
    } else if (event.keyCode == "68") {//68 D(RIGHT)
        if (startPx <= 410) {
            startPx += 20;
            gameData.redrawRequired = true;
        }
    } else if (event.keyCode == "72") { // 72 SPACEBAR ?? Actually H
        fireGun();
    }
}
```

3) Here's how you define a bullet object, and the firegun() function :

```
function Bullet() {
    // Object defining a bullet.
    this.x = startPx;
    this.y = startPy - 10;
    this.bulletSpeed = gameData.defaultBulletSpeed;
}

Bullet.prototype.draw = function () {
    // Draws the bullet on canvas...
    ctx.fillStyle = "#b20808";
    ctx.shadowColor = "#b20808";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 2, 8);
}

Bullet.prototype.move = function () {
    // Moves the bullet...
    this.y = this.y - this.bulletSpeed;
}


function fireGun() {
    var newBullet = new Bullet();
    gameData.allBullets.push(newBullet);
}
```

4) Then you decide when to redraw the canvas, using one main function (refreshGame) and another function to check if there are bullets to update (refreshBullets) :

```
function refreshBullets() {
    var i = 0;
    var currentBullet;
    // Start by eliminating bullets out of the screen...
    while (i < gameData.allBullets.length) {
        currentBullet = gameData.allBullets[i];
        if (currentBullet.y < -10) {
            gameData.allBullets.splice(i, 1); // Remove the bullet outside of the screen.
        } else {
            currentBullet.move();
            gameData.redrawRequired = true;
            i += 1; // Next bullet...
        }
    }
}


function refreshGame() {
    refreshBullets();
    if (gameData.redrawRequired) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        ctx.drawImage(img2, startPx, startPy);

        for (var i = 0; i < gameData.allBullets.length; i++) {
            gameData.allBullets[i].draw();
        }
    }
    gameData.redrawRequired = false;
}
```

5) And finally you initialize the whole, including setInterval in setUp() function :

```
function setUp() {
    project = document.getElementById("project");
    ctx = project.getContext("2d");
    width = 505;
    height = 900;
    mid = width / 2;
    midh = height / 2;
    startPx = width / 2 - 30;
    startPy = height - 150;

    audio = new Audio("bgm.mp3");
    audio.play();

    img = new Image();
    img2 = new Image();
    img.src = "bg.png";
    img2.src = "fighterjet.png"
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.shadowColor = "#ffffff";
        ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        ctx.drawImage(img2, startPx, startPy);
    }

    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress);

    // Here ! And do something about that start button or the game will start over again...
    gameData.interval = window.setInterval(refreshGame, 100);
    document.getElementById("start").style.display = "none";
    project.focus();
}
```

Notes :

- The canvas approach with setInterval is assumed to be a bad approach because of performances issues. Try to search for "javascript interval refresh with canvas", there are other ways to tackle the problem.
  The refreshRequired variable/property is only a placeholder to explain the workaround. Actually, you'll have to redraw the scene constantly as the background, targets and threats will move below the jet and you'll update score in the process.
- Before writing code, you should design the game, what are the goals, the characters, controls, limits, levels....... Paper and pencil is a good start. Problem is, when you start to write code before hand, you get stuck the moment you ask yourself, how do I make the bullet collide with the target ? And what if I can use missiles instead ? In the end, your code will get heavy and processor intensive because you attempted to solve a problem while creating another... Just an advice ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. These responses clarified things quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a setInterval every time you fire bullets.
You want to use one setInterval for the whole game that calls an update or draw function on each game object. 
For example

```js
var game={
  //this is a list of items in the game I want to move around or do stuff
  //nothing there yet
  objects:[]
}
//this is a bullet object which can be created calling new bullet()
function Bullet(){
   //IM CHEATING HERE. DON'T DRAW TO THE DOM FOR GAMES
   //this is just a shortcut instead of drawing on a canvas
  this.object=document.createElement('div');
  this.object.style.width="10px";
  this.object.style.height="10px";
  this.object.style.position='absolute';
  this.object.style.top="100px";
  this.object.style.backgroundColor='red';
  document.body.appendChild(this.object)
  ///
  //these hold the bullet's current location on screen
  this.x=100;
  this.y=100;

  //this is the update function that gets called every frame
  this.update=function(){
     //I'm updating the bullet's y position.
    this.y-=10;
    if(this.y>0){
     
      //don't draw to the dom like this. use canvas like you were doing.
      this.object.style.top=this.y+"px";
    }
  }
}

//now let's add a bullet to the game
game.objects.push(new bullet());

//the function that updates each of our objects
function runGame(){
  for(var i=0;i<game.objects.length;i++){
      game.objects[i].update();
  }
}
//start the game
setInterval(runGame, 1000)
```

**NOTE:** DO NOT draw on the DOM like this. Use canvas like you were doing. I just did the dom as a shortcut to demonstrate